# Issue with slony-I replication on postgres master and slave database

Tags: windows, postgresql, database-replication, slony

I have two system with OS windows 8 and windows XP. I installed the postgres plus advance server for database replication on both system. I followed this [link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/54798073/Tutorial-All-PP-Slony-Replication) for whole process.
But there is one issue with me to run the script written in **.sk** file extension. I have searched on google and stackoverflow but I didnot get any proper solution.

Can any one help me out to resolve this issue. If there is any query, frankly ask.

note:- this question may be duplicate on stackoverflow or any other.
Both are using on LAN and XP has domain admin account and windows 8 has local system admin account.

Comment: why voted to close this question? Can any one explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the .sk files are scripts which are run through slonik.  So something like

```
slonik myscript.sk
```

This being said, Slony-I is a very complex replication system and you are usually better off to look at streaming replication if your environment allows.